Examples of distributions with easily solvable quantile functions but hard to solve CDFs
I'm interested in examples of probability distributions where the quantile function $F^{-1}(p)$ exists in closed form or is easy to calculate but where the cumulative distribution function (CDF) $F(x)$ does not exist in closed form. In particular examples where the quantile function is easy to evaluate but the CDF is difficult or impossible to solve interest me, especially when the distribution is used in real world applications. Any example would be much appreciated!

I dont understand the downvote! I believe there are examples on site, will search when some more time

For a book-length answer to your question, see Statistical Modelling with Quantile Functions by Warren Gilchrist. In the following we assume random variables are continuous, let $F$ the the cdf of $X$, then the quantile function is the inverse of $F$,
$$ Q(p) = F^{-1}(p), p \in [0, 1] $$
$Q$ is then a monotonically increasing function, and importantly, any monotonically increasing function of argument $p\in [0,1]$ is the quantile function of some (real) random variable. That makes it easy to construct new quantile function from existing ones, making for flexibility in modeling,  and we can use that to easily make some quantile functions that do not have analytical inverses.
Some examples:
Sums of quantile functions are quantile functions
Sums of monotonically increasing functions are also monotonically increasing
Quantile functions to a positive power
A positive power $Q^\alpha$ of an increasing function is increasing
Convex combinations of quantile functions
If $Q_1, Q_2$ are increasing, then so is $\omega Q_1 + (1-\omega) Q_2$ for $0\le \omega \le 1$
Positive linear combinations of quantile functions
If $Q_1, Q_2$ are increasing, so is $a Q_1 + b  Q_2$ for $a\ge 0, b\ge 0$
Products of quantile functions corresponding to non-negative random variables
If $Q_1 \ge 0, Q_2 \ge 0$ then so is $Q_1 Q_2 \ge 0$. This also works if only one of the quantile functions correspond to a non-negative random variable.
(Some of this conditions can be summarized by saying that the set of quantile functions constitute a convex cone)
So for some examples we can construct using this.
The (standard) exponential distribution have quantile function $Q(p)=-\log(1-p)$. If we reflect this distribution in the $y$-axis, the quantile function becomes $\log p$. The sum of this quantile functions is
$$ \log(p) - \log(1-p) = \log\left( \frac{p}{1-p}  \right)$$
which is the quantile function of the logistic distribution. If we take a convex combination,
$$\alpha \log p - (1-\alpha) \log(1-p)$$
we get a skew distribution, the skew logistic, which do not have an analytic cdf.
The quantile function of the standard uniform random variable is $Q(p)=p$. We can combine this linearly with the logistic to get
$$Q(p)= \log\left( \frac{p}{1-p}  \right) + Kp, K>0$$
which will have the effect of flattening the maximum. This quantile function can not be inverted analytically, either. Now you have the tools to construct many examples yourself!
(I will add some plots later)

This is a great answer.

I like your use of monotonously increasing (perhaps suggested by a spellchecker) but I think monotonically increasing may be more common.

Thanks a lot for this answer!

"Monotonic" means always the same (unchanging; in the same direction); "monotonous" means boring ;-).

@whuber: Thanks, will edit ... not a native english speaker (or writer)

+1 But doesn't the second example (quantile functions to a positive power) also require non-negative random variables?

Assuming you mean evaluate rather than solve*, the Tukey lambda distributions have easily evaluated quantile functions but the cdf doesn't have closed form
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tukey_lambda_distribution
Among other uses, particular members of the family were somewhat commonly used in the past to produce approximate normal scores.

* Let me explain why I am making a deal about whether you mean evaluate rather than solve. The distinction between evaluate and solve is central to the question being answered. It's not just me pedantically insisting on conventionally-correct terminology in this instance;  changing from evaluate to solve quite literally flips us from the easy case to the hard case and vice versa:
While $F^{-1}(p)$ is readily calculated by direct substitution, ('easy' per your conditions), if I set $F^{-1}(p) = x_0$ and try to solve that equation to obtain $p$, it is hard. Indeed, it's equivalent to the task of evaluating $F$ itself. If we could solve that equation easily, we could evaluate $F$ easily. Typically you'd need to use some iterative root finding method or some series approximation etc, which is not nearly so straightforward.

I see what you mean. I did mean evaluate. I'll update the question!
